# Jump to the last postion when open Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

my intention it is to get a simply feature which jump to the last cell in GoogleSheet from where I have closed the file. I have written this script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var column = cell.getColumn();
  var sheet_name = sheet.getSheetName();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  scriptProperties.setProperty('row',row);
  scriptProperties.setProperty('column',column);
  scriptProperties.setProperty('sheet name',sheet_name);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet_name = properties.getProperty('sheet name');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  var row = properties.getProperty('row');
  var column = properties.getProperty('column');
  var cell = sheet.getRange(row,column);

  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  ss.setActiveRange(cell);  
}
```

The Script write the values into the Property filed but when I open the file nothing happend.

For a better demonstation you can find my script here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cAsWRNl9f5jxjvgDh17l4C43bhxJdulWyaNXmLwuab0/edit?usp=sharing

Does anyone know where my bug is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

In your script, you put and get the values using PropertiesService. In this case, the values of number type are put as the string type. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

When the Spreadsheet is opened, `row` and `column` are retrieved from PropertiesService. In this case, `row` and `column` are the string values. By this, an error occurs at `var cell = sheet.getRange(row,column);` in the function of `onOpen`. Because `row` and `column` are not the number values.

I think that when you turn off the V8 runtime at the script editor, `var cell = sheet.getRange(row,column);` works. (From the script of your shared Spreadsheet, I thought that you use the script with V8.) But when the V8 runtime is used, an error occurs. I think that this might be the specification of V8.

So in order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(row,column);
```

##### To:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(Number(row), Number(column));
```

Or

Turn off the V8 runtime at the script editor.

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer))

  > - row, Integer, The row index of the cell to return; row indexing starts with 1.
  > - column, Integer, The column index of the cell to return; column indexing starts with 1.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your perfect answer. It works fine:
Way 1: I switch off the Version V8
Way 2: I changed the commandline

Comment: @J. Doe Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.